# Logback: Can you use AsyncAppender inside SiftingAppender?

Tags: java, logback

Reading http://blog.takipi.com/how-to-instantly-improve-your-java-logging-with-7-logback-tweaks/ , it is suggested that FileAppender is very slow compared with AsyncAppender.

I currently have a SiftingAppender then uses FileAppender to write to file. If I change FileAppender with AsyncAppender->FileAppender will this give me a significant performance increase (assuming it is possible)?

Answer (score 2):

No. You can't have multiple appenders inside `SiftingAppender`.
See http://logback.qos.ch/codes.html#1andOnly1

However you can put `AsyncAppender` outside with almost same result.
So your appender chain may look like this:
`ROOT -> AsyncAppender -> SiftingAppender -> FileAppender`